# Items from previous UITableView appearing in new UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, xamarin.ios

I am having an issue with my tableviews as I pop one tableview off my navigation controller and then pushing a new one on with similar data for the source.  Somehow I am seeing cells from the old tableview.  Any ideas?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing code, but most likely culprit for this kind of error is if you are adding subviews to your tableView cells in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` instead of modifying existing ones. Then, when the cells are reused, those subViews still exist and are appearing, even though you're also creating additional ones.

Comment: Wow, just figured it out, I was dequeing cells to increase responsiveness and storing the references in memory, and when I popped the old tableview off I was setting it to animate the pop.  This somehow held the cells in memory just long enough so that when I pushed the new UITableView on the stack, it was accessing the de-qued cells and presenting them instead of the new data.  So if you plan on presenting similar data and are popping off a UITableView to replace it with the new data, pop it without animation...

Comment: Nice catch! I bet `[self.tableView reloadData];` flushes the cache as well, so you could pop with an animation and then call reload.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if these are two different table views you probably want to give them different reuse identifiers, e.g.

for the FirstTable:
UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"FirstTableViewCell"];

for the SecondTable:
UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SecondTableViewCell"];

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, in my case I was only having the issue when popping it off and replacing it with a refreshed list.  It will be helpful to know for the future!

Answer (score 1):

Wow, just figured it out, I was dequeing cells (And using Custom Cells) to increase responsiveness and storing the references in memory, and when I popped the old tableview off I was setting it to animate the pop.  This somehow held the cells in memory just long enough so that when I pushed the new UITableView on the stack, it was accessing the de-qued cells and presenting them instead of the new data.  So if you plan on presenting similar data and are popping off a UITableView to replace it with the new data, pop it without animation...
Or give them a specifically unique identifier as mentioned above. (But my solution was just to avoid using animation.